# Create a data frame R

Tags: xml, r, dataframe

I'm running the next code in R:

```
library(xml2)

doc <- read_html('http://www.southcarolinagasprices.com/GasPriceSearch.aspx?typ=adv&fuel=A&srch=0&area=All%20Areas&station=All%20Stations&tme_limit=4')

prices <- xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//div[@class='sp_p']")

sapply(prices, function(x) {
as.numeric(paste(gsub("d", "\\.", 
                    gsub("^p", "", 
                         unlist(xml_attrs(xml_find_all(x, "./div"))))),
               collapse=""))
})

##   [1] 1.65 1.65 1.65 1.65 1.65 1.65 1.65 1.65 1.65 1.67 1.68 1.69 1.69 1.69 1.69 1.69 1.69 1.69 1.69
##  [20] 1.70 1.71 1.72 1.72 1.73 1.73 1.73 1.73 1.73 1.73 1.73 1.73 1.73 1.74 1.74 1.74 1.74 1.74 1.74
##  [39] 1.74 1.74 1.74 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.75 1.76 1.76
##  [58] 1.76 1.76 1.76 1.76 1.76 1.76 1.76 1.76 1.76 1.76 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77
##  [77] 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77
##  [96] 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78
## [115] 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78
## [134] 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.78 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79
## [153] 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79
## [172] 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79
## [191] 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79 1.79
```

How can I convert this values to a data.frame ? I need to export this values to export to .csv or .txt

Comment: Will the dimensions have any constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    library(xml2)

    doc <- read_html('http://www.southcarolinagasprices.com/GasPriceSearch.aspx?   typ=adv&fuel=A&srch=0&area=All%20Areas&station=All%20Stations&tme_limit=4')

    prices <- xml_find_all(doc, xpath="//div[@class='sp_p']")

    test<-sapply(prices, function(x) {
    as.numeric(paste(gsub("d", "\\.", 
                        gsub("^p", "", 
                             unlist(xml_attrs(xml_find_all(x, "./div"))))),
                   collapse=""))
    })
df_test<-data.frame(test)
write.csv(df_test, file=df_test.csv)
```